# CPGraphHostingView background image issue in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I have a `CPGraphHostingView` to display a graph. I changed its theme to clear color, and add a `UIImageView` to the `CPGraphHostingView` in order to add an image as the background of the graph.

But then the image will give only the mirror image like copy of the original image. So when I am taking the screenshot of that view I'm getting the mirror image copy of the original view. How to solve this?

Comment: you will have to show us your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add any subviews to the `CPGraphHostingView`. If you must use a `UIImageView`, make it a sibling of the hosting view (i.e., they are both subviews of the same parent).

The easiest way to put an image behind a graph is to set the `fill`.

```
CPTImage backgroundImage = [CPTImage imageForPNGFile:pathToTheImage];
graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:backgroundImage];
```

You can also create the image using `+imageWithCGImage:` or `+imageWithCGImage:scale:` if you already have your background image loaded into a `CGImageRef`.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but my background is still transparent. What  is the format for the string `pathToTheImage`, how cant I acces my _background.png_ stored in my _images_ file